# Formula for comparing values in two worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

can someone help me on this.I want a formula for the below scenario

I have sheet 1 in which Ii have

```
  A                 B     C
NAME              TYPE  VALUE
lock_name_space    2    
processes          3     200
sessions           3     324
timed_statistics   1     TRUE
```

and in sheet2 I have

```
  A                B         C
NAME             TYPE      VALUE
processes         3        200
sessions          3        324
timed_statistics  1       FALSE
```

I want a formula to compare A of sheet 1 with A of sheet2,if it is present in sheet 2 of A then check its value(ie C column) is same if same return TRUE else FALSE
eg.In sheet1 I have timed_statistics   1 TRUE ,in sheet 2 I have timed_statistics   1   FALSE
and in sheet1 I have lock_name_space and in sheet 2 I dont have lock_name_space

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with VBA and result can be achieved with excels built-in functions. Please check your tags.

Answer (score 0):

With a function in a cell can be written to each line on your "sheet1" (supposing this will be placed on row 2). -

```
=IF(C2=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!A:C;3;FALSE);TRUE;FALSE)
```

Or if you want to leave error values to false too then

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!A:C;2;FALSE);TRUE;FALSE);FALSE)
```

After that if you want to check if all params are True you can use =AND() and =OR() functions, depending what result you want (in your case supposedly being =AND())

Answer (score 0):

How about this formula on sheet 1 in column D:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C;MATCH(A2;Sheet2!A:A;0))=C2;"not on sheet 2")
```

The above formula would go in row 2 and you'd have to copy it down.

Note, that this works only for Excel 2010 and above since it makes use of IFERROR. If you have a prior version of Excel you'll have to break it down into an IF-statement combined with an ISERROR.